# How do I avoid a query (get) from a service being executed multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have a service which looks likes the following:

```
var chatServices = angular.module('chatServices', ['ngResource']);

chatServices.factory('Chat',['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('sample-chat-data.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
    });
  }
]);
```

I have two controllers, one for the main and one for the detailed view:

```
  chatListApp.controller('ChatItemsController', ['$scope', 'Chat', "$location",
    function ($scope, Chat, $location) {
      $scope.chatitems = Chat.query();
      $scope.detailPage = function (hash) { 
        $location.path(hash);
      }
    }]);

  chatListApp.controller('ChatDetailController', ['$scope', "$routeParams", "Chat",
    function ($scope, $routeParams, Chat) {
      $scope.chatID = $routeParams.chatID; 
      $scope.chatitems = Chat.query(function() { 
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.chatitems.length; i++) { 
          if ($scope.chatitems[i].id === $scope.chatID) { 
            $scope.chat = $scope.chatitems[i]; 
            break; 
          } 
        };
      });
    }]);
```

I have a feeling that my code is far from optimal, and the reason is I am doing the same query, two times. Is there a smart way to do this? Can I somehow save/cache the result of my service to a variable?

You can see the full code and an online working example of the SPA there: https://github.com/gkatsanos/angular-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn on your cache

```
chatServices.factory('Chat',['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('sample-chat-data.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true,cache : true}
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: so saving the result of my return in a variable is not an option?

Comment: actually to do it with variable is not so accurate way, because for saving requests we already have chache flag, why dont use it ? :) it more simple and nice way for me